# I've forgotten my Electrum 12 word pass phrase, I have full access to the wallet - can I recover or generate new one?

Tags: electrum, passphrase

I've forgotten my Electrum 12 word passphrase, but I have full access to the wallet. Can I recover or generate a new one?

I can't find anything online about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passphrase can be viewed from Wallet > Seed option

[image]

Comment: Thanks - when I type that into a new wallet on another machine, the next button is still greyed out?!

Comment: @nico please check this thread https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1898620.0

Comment: Thanks - it has now let me click through - but it's showing a balance of 0?!

Comment: @niico Do the addresses for the new wallet match the addresses in the old wallet?

Comment: I must have typed it wrong - working now thx.